# In a MS install, can you allow different users to have their own themes?

Tags: multisite, themes

Is it possible in a MS install to allow network site admins to edit their own themes? For example, I would like to give everyone access to theme ABC, but if one user edits that theme, they seamlessly create their own instance of the theme, so no other user's theme is affected. I believe the short answer is "no" so I'm wondering if there are any good ideas about how to implement this kind of system.

Comment: What kind of edits are you talking about?

Comment: Any kind of change at all. Using the web-based theme edtior, changing style.css, etc.

Comment: I had some ideas for simple chamges. Guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as WordPress is open source, if you have control of your server, you can technically do anything :-) Depending on your skill set, that may or may not be feasible.

A low tech solution would be to create a copy of the theme ABC for each user. Change the folder name, and change the **Theme Name** in the comment at the top of style.css to personalise it to each user (e.g. "ABC for Bob", "ABC for Clare"). The [codex on child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) is a good starting point for information about this.

I'm not aware of any API calls to detect changes through the theme editor, so I think you'd have to patch the core WordPress install. I had a brief search for where this might be. Using exec() to copy the theme directory would be pretty simple, but the user interaction and updating which version of the theme is being used could make it a bit more complicated.

Of course this is further complicated by the fact that the 'edit' function on a multisite is only available to the network admins.

Comment: I guess this answer fits the question.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I have what's required to make these changes and I just wanted to check in with someone before I went ahead and patched the core and did some work. My only concern now is creating many many files by repeatedly copying theme files, but I'm not sure there's any way around this.

Comment: You could make each copied theme a child, and just copy the changed files?